# nginx error log skip rule

Tags: logging, nginx

I keep getting a request for /var/www/html/[ with square bracket in nginx error log, I can't find what generates such call.

Is there a way to skip choking my logs with this thing?

Comment: That may be some hacker requests... Can you show a sample of a said line?

Comment: Could be a case where a CMS tries mistakenly treats certain characters around a URL to be part of it.